# Unique email address with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm running ExpressJS with Sequelize/MySQL and trying very hard to get a simple validator check working for unique email address.

Here is my user model. And for the life of me I don't understand why this is allowing records that have duplicate email address. Surely the email.unique=true would be preventing this.

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {
    firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
    lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: {
          msg: "Must be a valid email address",
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    indexes: [{
      fields: ['email'],
      unique: true,
    }]
  });
  return User;
};
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
As requested here is the controller code for create user.

```
const User = require('../models').User;

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  User.create( req.body )
  .then( user => {
    res.json( user );
  })
  .catch( errors => {
    res.json({ errors: errors.errors });
  });
};
```

Comment: Please also post the code for create/add user

Comment: Ended up adding the validator found in the link below instead. Seems like something Sequelize should do anyway but it works.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2640#issuecomment-345472446

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is by using `sequelize.sync()` to create your table according to the schema specified in the model if the table exists then you should pass `{force: true}` to the sync method, the table will be dropped and a new one will be created.

though using `sequelize.sync()` is not highly recommended especially in production due to issues with migration files etc, you can google than for more details.